# C# how to Make function/Method Wait without blocking program (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fork, wait

I want to simulate health regeneration in my game in unity, in the function `RestoreHealth()`.

Am I overthinking it by wanting to create a child process, so when I call wait, it won't affect any current running process or thread and the child process will die when the function is done.

```
public void RestoreHealth() {
    if (health >= MaxHealth) return; // health and MaxHealth are Class variables

    if (health % 10 != 0) {     // if health is not dividable by 10
        int temp = health % 10; // then we round it to the closest 
                                //tenth
        temp = 10 - temp;
        health += temp;
    }

    int i = health;

    for (; i < MaxHealth; i += 10) {  // where the health grows till 100
        health += 10;
        // sleep(1000);  // make function wait for '1 second' to iterate again

        Debug.Log("Health: " + health);
    }
}
```

How do I create a child process in C# or unity in this case and cause it to wait?

Is there an equivalent to `Fork();` like in C?

Also, this function is called when the player initially receives damage.

**Solution**:

note: I changed Health to Armour

```
public IEnumerator RestoreArmour() {
        while (_Armour < _MaxArmour) {
            _Armour++;
            Debug.Log("Health: " + _Armour);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(ArmourRegenRate); // ArmourRegenRate is a 
                                                             // float for the seconds
        }
    }
```

and use this to initiate the coroutine

```
 void Start(){

    StartCoroutine(player.RestoreArmour());
}
```

Comment: `fork()` doesn't create a process.  It creates a *thread*.  Yes, you can create threads in C#.

Comment: In unity you can't create threads because unity only runs on the main thread for multi-threading you would have to use a server and query the server to perform actions @Amy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Basic Coroutine concept

In Unity you work with Coroutines to achieve this asychronous "threaded" behaviour

```
IEnumerator RestoreHealth() {
   while (health != MaxHealth) {
       health++;
       yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
   }
}
```

and then invoke it with

```
StartCoroutine(RestoreHealth());
```

---

### Restarting a Coroutine

In order to stop an existing Coroutine from running and start a new one, this is how you would achieve that:

```
private Coroutine _myCoroutine = null;

void SomeMethod()
{
    if (_myCoroutine != null)
        StopCoroutine(_myCoroutine);

    _myCoroutine = StartCoroutine(SomeOtherMethod());
}
```

---

### Pausing armor restoration for X seconds when player has taken damage

A common functionality is to have something restore armor when player hasn't taken damage for X seconds:

```
private bool _shouldRestoreArmour = true;
private Coroutine _pauseArmorCoroutine = null;

void Update()
{
    if (_shouldRestoreArmour)
        Armor += ArmorRegenerationPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
}

void PlayerTakeDamage() 
{
    if (_pauseArmorCoroutine != null) 
        StopCoroutine(_pauseArmorCoroutine);

    _pauseArmorCoroutine = StartCoroutine(PauseRestoreArmor());

    // Take damage code
}

IEnumerator PauseRestoreArmor()
{
    _shouldRestoreArmor = false;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(RESTORE_ARMOR_DELAY_TIME);
    _shouldRestoreArmor = true;
}
```

Here the player will regenerate armor at all times, except for X seconds after the player has taken damage. If the player takes damage multiple times we will simply abort the previous coroutine and start a new one, so that it will be a fresh X seconds from the last hit.

Comment: I replace 'WaitForEndOfFrame(); with 
'yield return new WaitForSeconds(ArmourRegenRate); ' instead

Comment: Great! Whatever works for you, I just wanted to show the concept here. Remember that these things are _asynchronous_, meaning you should make sure to only start ONE of these at the time, unless you need multiple of the running asynchronously, of course.

Comment: I see the update in your original post; that implementation looks great!

Comment: hmm, so this RestoreArmour() function would be called every time the player is Damaged, if the player gets hit again while the armour is regenerating, 
then it would be bad, i need to halt the current running function and restart it

Comment: Ah, yes. A common use-case; a debouncer functionality. I'll update my code to show you how I usually implement this. 1 sec

Comment: Hehe, it's actually not but I hear that a lot! I'm from Sweden, the name is a war name :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a timer assuming that you run this in the update method

```c#
private float timer = 1;
private float timerReset = 1;

private void Update(){
  RestoreHealth();
}

public void RestoreHealth() {
  if (health >= MaxHealth) return; // health and MaxHealth are Class variables

  if (health % 10 != 0) {     // if health is not dividable by 10
    int temp = health % 10; // then we round it to the closest tenth
    temp = 10 - temp;
    health += temp;
  }
  int i = health;
  for (; i < MaxHealth; i += 10) {  // where the health grows till 100
    if(timer > 0){
      timer -= 1 * time.deltaTime;
    }else{
      health += 10;
      Debug.Log("Health: " + health);
      timer = timerReset;
    }
  }

}
```

or you can simply just give your player 1 health every second or whatever amount for instance

```c#
    public void RestoreHealth() {
      if (health >= MaxHealth) return; // health and MaxHealth are Class variables

      if (health % 10 != 0) {     // if health is not dividable by 10
        int temp = health % 10; // then we round it to the closest tenth
        temp = 10 - temp;
        health += temp;
      }
      int i = health;
      for (; i < MaxHealth; i += 10) {  // where the health grows till 100

          health += 10 * 1 * time.deltaTime;
          Debug.Log("Health: " + health);
          timer = timerReset;

      }

    }
```

So in this scenario your player recieves 10 health every second but the value will always go up so in the matter of a second the player health would go up 1 health every 100ms

Comment: won't this be an infinite loop because the timer is always reset to 1?

also, this function is called when the player initially receives damage.

Comment: It only gets reset once the timer has counted down all the way to zero then it is reset

Comment: yeah i works but i want a more noticeable slow increment. thanks though